# Dynamic Scalar Sub Queries

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

How to generate Scalar Sub Queries dynamically at run time using Java. 
Please suggest any api if available?

Scalar sub query example:

```
SELECT d.deptno, d.dname, (SELECT count(*) FROM emp e
                            WHERE e.deptno = d.deptno) AS "Num Dept"
 FROM dept d;
```

For example take hotel reservation application. user can search on different criteria.
I want to construct scalar subquery based on this criteria.

Can we do this in Hibernate Criteria API or JPA 2.0 Criteria API.
But I want to use native SQL in my DAO....

Comment: Maybe if you gave an example of what you mean by "Scalar Sub Query" and "dynamically"... as it stands your question is vague at best.  Also, if this is a homework question, please add the "homework" tag.

Comment: If you want to use native SQL you're going to have to generate the queries yourself.  What sort of API assistance are you looking for?

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Using squiggle sql builder. Using this API we can create complex SQL. But I am not sure whether we can create Scalar Sub Queries